# How to manually add multiple json key value pair using angular input?

Tags: angular

I have to create dynamic object like using input from view 
(user can add multiple key and values)
Example: "data":[{"Terms": "{"metaDataKey": ["metaData", "metaData"]},
              {"hero: ["value1", "Value2"]}"}]

```
 <tr>
                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                <input [(ngModel)]="metaDataKey" matInput formControlName="metaDataKey"
                                       autocomplete="off"
                                       placeholder="Meta Data Key">
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                                <mat-chip-list #metaDataChipList>
                                    <mat-chip *ngFor="let term of metaData" [selectable]="selectable"
                                              [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(term, metaData)">
                                        {{term}}
                                        <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                                    </mat-chip>
                                    <input name="metaData" placeholder="Meta Data"
                                           [matChipInputFor]="metaDataChipList"
                                           [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                                           [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                                           (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
                                </mat-chip-list>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </td></tr>
```

Comment: Please help me to develop this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: term is string, term need to be an array of object 

term = [
{

},
{

}
]

Comment: please share you code what you have done so far

Comment: Please find my html code for key value pair. here only one time i can insert. But need to enter multiple key and values how to achieve this. please help

Comment: @Mak is it possible if you put this on stackblitz so we can input our code/test it out too

Comment: Also, ngFor iterates over `metaData`, but your array of data is called `data`?

Comment: @TheParam, I have shared my code above